# SASS mapped property doesn't enter in IF else statement

Tags: sass, libsass, sass-maps

I'm just pulling my hair right know.

I have a mixing that receives a simple object. Depending on the value of one of the properties should enter inside de IF statement **or the ELSE one**.
However it's always evaluating as TRUE and can't figure why.

Code is compiled using node-sass (libsass v3.5.4 ) and the gist can be seen here:

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/40eb28fd55173d7534a7162de3c1b960

Both times calculateHeight mixin is invoked evaluates the if to TRUE and creates a **CSS with twice color: red, instead of color: red and color: blue**

```
// ----
// libsass (v3.5.4)
// ----

$headerHeight: 150px;
$headerHeightM: 115px;
$headerHeightS: 100px;

@mixin calculateHeight($obj:()){    

    @if #{map-get($obj, value)} {       
        color: red;
        @media (min-width: 480px) {     
            #{map-get($obj, property)}: $headerHeightS;
        }
        @media (min-width: 768px) {     
            #{map-get($obj, property)}: $headerHeightM;
        }
        @media (min-width: 1280px) {                
            #{map-get($obj, property)}: $headerHeight;  
        }
    }

    @else {

        color: blue;
        @media (min-width: 480px) {     
            #{map-get($obj, property)}: #{map-get($obj, value)} 233px;
        }
    }

}
.header{
  @include calculateHeight((property: 'height', value: false));
  @include calculateHeight((property: "background", value: "url('../img/red_header_wave_1.png') no-repeat center top/100% "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but, **if I assign the value of the object property to a variable** it does the trick and works. Again, not sure why but it's working now:

```
// ----
// libsass (v3.5.4)
// ----

$headerHeight: 150px;
$headerHeightM: 115px;
$headerHeightS: 100px;

@mixin calculateHeight($obj:()){    

// Assign the mapped property to a variable prior to @if
$var: #{map-get($obj, value)};
    @if $var == 'false' {       
        color: red;
        @media (min-width: 480px) {     
            #{map-get($obj, property)}: $headerHeightS;
        }
        @media (min-width: 768px) {     
            #{map-get($obj, property)}: $headerHeightM;
        }
        @media (min-width: 1280px) {                
            #{map-get($obj, property)}: $headerHeight;  
        }
    }

    @else {

        color: blue;
        @media (min-width: 480px) {     
            #{map-get($obj, property)}: #{map-get($obj, value)} 233px;
        }
    }

}
.header{
  @include calculateHeight((property: 'height', value: false));
  @include calculateHeight((property: "background", value: "url('../img/red_header_wave_1.png') no-repeat center top/100% "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are interpolating the value from your map into a string, so you are actually checking the string `"false"`, which is truthy (as you already found out). Get rid of the interpolation `#{...}` and it should work as expected.

```
- @if #{map-get($obj, value)} {
+ @if map-get($obj, value) {
```